# Swiper: Swipe to next item only with a button and to previous items manually

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WC2JanXhDeQ) to show  some items.

I want to swipe to next item only when a button is clicked, but letting to swipe manually to previous items.

Those are the relevant options related to swiping:

> **allowSwipeToPrev**: Set to false to disable swiping to previous slide direction (to left or top)
>
> **allowSwipeToNext**: Set to false to disable swiping to next slide direction (to right or bottom)
>
> **swipeHandler**: String with CSS selector or HTML element of the container with pagination that will work as **only** available handler for swiping
>
> **nextButton**: String with CSS selector or HTML element of the element that will work like "next" button after click on it
>
> **prevButton**: String with CSS selector or HTML element of the element that will work like "prev" button after click on it

If I use `swipeHandler` as the button selector, it works as expected, except that I cannot swipe to previous item since it *works as **only** available handler for swiping*. No matter what other options I use.

If I set `allowSwipeToNext` to false and use `nextButton` instead of `swipeHandler`, it won't swipe to next item, even when I click the *next* button.

So the question is: **How can I achieve to swipe to next item only with a button and to previous items only manually?**

Comment: Sorry, seems logical if you disable the swipeToNext that you can't swipe to next. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Well I just want to disable **manual** swipe to next, but keeping swiping to next with a button and swiping to prev manually.

Answer (score 6):

had the same problem and solved like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 30,
});
// Locks the swipe to next by default
swiper.lockSwipeToNext();

$("#button_id").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Unlocks the swipe to next when the button is clicked
  swiper.unlockSwipeToNext();
  // Swipes to the next slide
  swiper.slideNext();
  // Locks the swipe to next again after moving to the next slide
  swiper.lockSwipeToNext();
});
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: For me `unlockSwipeToNext()` was not a function. `slideNext()` works fine though!

Answer (score 1):

To disable touch control:

```
mySwiper.disableTouchControl();
```